# How to get batch file to call other batch files but only run certain ones

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that asks which program to install then points to that program using a batch file. There are multiple batch files in it but only need to run the one they choose.

I have tried GOTO and IF ELSE but none are working.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set fs=\\
 echo.
  if not defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
  set comparch=Computer is 32-bit
  set progfile=%ProgramFiles%
  ) else (
  set comparch=Computer is 64-bit
  set progfile=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
  )
  echo %comparch%
:: FINDS VAST ON ANY DRIVE
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%drive%:\Program Files (x86)\My Software\Testing\" (
    set drive=%%d
  )
)

if exist "%drive%:Program Files (x86)\My Software\Testing\Test.exe" (
    ECHO Office location
    set sqlinst=OFFICE
) else (
    ECHO Shop location
    set sqlinst=POS
)

echo.
echo Requirements:
echo       1. Please confirm the above information before continuing
echo.
pause
CLS
REM shows setup options
:setupask
Echo =============================================
echo     SHORTCUT SETUP 
Echo =============================================
if "%sqlinst%" == "OFFICE" (
    if "!concomphier!" == "y" (
        ECHO     m = MPI
        ECHO     c = Cat
        ECHO     q = Quit
    ) else (
        ECHO     m = MPI
        ECHO     c = Cat
        ECHO     q = Quit
    )
) else (
    if "!concomphier!" == "y" (
    :: if computer is a workstation display the following
        ECHO     m = MPI
        ECHO     c = Cat
        ECHO     q = Quit
    ) else (
    :: if computer is a server display the following
        ECHO     m = MPI
        ECHO     c = Cat
        ECHO     q = Quit
    )
)
ECHO. 
ECHO NOTE: Once you place input in this step everything else is automated!
Echo =============================================

set /p shortcut_install="Which setup would you like to run?: "
ECHO.
if "%shortcut_install%" == "m"
call %~dp0MPIInstall.bat
GOTO END

if "%shortcut_install%" == "c"
(
GOTO CATINSTALL
::CATINSTALL
call %~dp0CatInstall.bat
GOTO END
)
) else if "%shortcut_install%" == "q" (
    CLS
    EXIT /B 0
)
::END
ECHO %prognameshort% shortcut creation complete!!
ECHO.
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
goto setupask
pause
```

I am expect that when they choose m it will bring up the batch file MPIInstall.bat then ask to quit

I expect that when they choose c it will bring up the batch file Catinstall.bat then ask to quit

Comment: I might have a moment to actually comb through your block and give you an answer, but at first glance: you set variables you never use (fs, progfile), you use variables before setting their values (drive), you `GOTO` places that are already immediately after the `GOTO` (CATINSTALL), and just the general structure of the code needs to be refined a bit.

Comment: Thank you, if you could please look through it. I am not a master yet of batch files. I added the GOTO so it would just use that and then go to the end.

Comment: does this install to the 32-bit program files directory regardless of whether your operating system is 32-bit?

Comment: It should look to see if it is 32 bit or 64 bit and install it in %drive%:\Program Files (x86)\My Software\Testing\

Comment: and if there are multiple drives with a Program Files subfolder, do you want to run the installation on every drive? what are the chances that it is going to be anything other than C:\ ?

Comment: Basically, one of the biggest issues is that your installation assumes you're on the 64-bit version because it specifies "Program Files (x86)" - which on the 32-bit version is just going to be "Program Files" - on top of that, since it's unclear how many drives you actually need to install on, you are doing a lot of extra steps - whereas if it's just one drive, it should be set in your environment variable as `%PROGRAMFILES%` (32-bit) or `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` (64-bit).

Comment: There is a chance its either on the C or the D drive basically. I changed the program files to show correctly. The main part is getting this to use only one of the batch files and not run all of them.

Comment: You already use system variables like `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, Why searching them in all drives? Do you really have/expect a `Program Files (x86)` folder on several drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your question, you just need to make sure your `IF ELSE` statements are formatted correctly and that your `GOTO` commands are useful. If you're trying to loop through your installation options until the user gives the exit command, you would structure it like this:

```
@echo off

:TRYAGAIN
set /p input="Enter A B or C: "
if /i %input% == A (
    echo APPLE
    ) else (
        if /i %input% == B (
        echo BANANA
        ) else (
            if /i %input% == C (
            echo CLEMENTINE
            ) else (
            echo WE JUST CAN'T HAVE NICE THINGS
            pause
            exit
        )
    )
)
GOTO TRYAGAIN
```

I didn't put your code in the block so you could copy and paste this into your own batch and get a feel for how it works. Essentially you'll just replace the letters with your own, and the `echo FRUIT` with `call YOURBATCHFILE`.

Beyond that, I would seriously look at what you're currently trying to do with your main batch file and see what's actually necessary and what isn't. For example: if all of your install/user input options are the same (<kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, and <kbd>q</kbd>) what is the point in determining the type or location of the computer you're running the batch on? You can make it as fancy/complicated as you want, but if you don't plan on doing anything with the information you're gathering - there's no point in gathering it.

With a general overview of what you're attempting to accomplish, you could likely get by with having *just* the `IF ELSE` block and let the batch files they call handle the drive letter using a variable substring and `cd` like this:

```
set "dir=%cd:~0,2%"
if exist "%dir%\Program Files (x86)" (...etc.
```

but if you really want to comb through your available drives, you could use a block like this and add/remove letters to your heart's content:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (C: D: E:) do (
    if exist "%%A\Program Files (x86)" (
        echo %%A Drive is 64-bit
        set "dir=%%A\Program Files (x86)\My Software\Testing"
        call :install %%A
    ) else (
        if exist "%%A\Program Files" (
        echo echo %%A Drive is 32-bit
        set "dir=%%A\Program Files\My Software\Testing"
        call :install %%A
        )
    )
)

:install
```

where `:install` is a subroutine that will process your installation walkthrough for each available drive. There are a ton of options and stuff you can do, but you'll need to figure out *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish and what information you need to build on top of your basic `IF ELSE` foundation.

Reference: [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [variable substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), and [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)